# What stack does a vectored exception handler use (Windows)?

Tags: c, windows

I have a toy programming language that uses a separate stack for each coroutine/fiber/thread. The stack is initially allocated using MEM_RESERVE via VirtualAlloc on Windows, to reduce committed memory. I've added a vectored exception handler that catches page faults that occur when the stack grows, and calls VirtualAlloc again on these pages with MEM_COMMIT.

The problem I have is that my vectored exception handler (set up via AddVectoredExceptionHandler) is not running. I suspect this is due to a double stack fault. The theory is that the program runs out of MEM_COMMIT stack, and starts the exception handler. Since the exception handler uses the same stack (possibly?) it also immediately faults, and thus never runs.

**So, does the handler use the same stack as the coroutine/fiber that faulted?** Is there any way to make vectored exception handlers use a special stack? (On Unix-like systems, I use sigaltstack for this purpose).

Comment: For stack overflows you can make your handler run by using SetThreadStackGuarantee  and _resetstkoflw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the VC2008 documentation:

> **Vectored Exception Handling**
>
> Vectored handlers are not frame-based, therefore, you can add a handler that will be called regardless of where you are in a call frame.

The "regardless of where you are in a call frame" makes me expect that the exception handler uses the current stack (`sp` register).

To make sure, reserve some space before "the program runs out of MEM_COMMIT stack" to allow the handler to use the stack, and use a debugger to check the  assembler sequence of instructions and the registers.

Comment: Yep, your theory was right. I added a guard page at the end of the MEM_COMMIT range of the stack (right before the MEM_RESERVE range). Windows does not change the stack pointer before calling the vectored exception handler.